# Mysql Fraction Seconds in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, milliseconds

I have a column that supports fractional seconds (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) but I can't find a way to make Rails/ActiveRecord to store a time without chopping the fractional seconds.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Support for fractional seconds for MySQL 5.6 and above was added in [Rails 4.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#active-record-notable-changes) (search for "fractional" on the page).

If you can't upgrade Rails you can try to patch ActiveRecord MySQL adapter like [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8240/files)